# Joomla homepage 404 page not found

Tags: joomla

After uninstalling joomfish module I can no longer acces the home page, it just redirect to the 404 page not found.

Unfortunately i dont have any backup of my previous version of the db and cant get to fix it.

Comment: Did you uninstall Joomla entirely?

Comment: No, only joomlafish module has been unistalled...

Comment: Then why not mention that in the question? Apart from Jon Skeet, there are no brain-readers here on [SO] that I know of. Well, without any logs, or other clues about the error why it does that, it would be hard to tell what the problem is. But you could try accessing the backend to see if that works...

Comment: the backend works fine

Comment: Well, then the battle is not lost. Check all the menu settings, and articles to exist...

Comment: what do u exactly mean by check all the menu setting? i have not deleted any of the articles, i just deleted joomfish module, and from that moment it leads me to 404 page

Comment: check this http://www.pastrimi.info/

and this which works: http://www.pastrimi.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=116&Itemid=551&lang=en

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you have deleted the article that was associated with the homepage menu item.

Create a quick test article and assign it the the homepage menu link to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: if i go this way http://www.pastrimi.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=116&Itemid=551&lang=en, i can open the page, but if i go only www.pastrimi.info, it should by default open one of the category menu as i have defined as default page.

Comment: do you have a "Home" menu item that is set as "default"?

Comment: I have another menu that is set as default